# packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Broken pipe

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, google-compute-engine

What does it mean when the terminal throw this error and how to solve it?

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Broken pipe
```

It was just happen today. After it work normally for year.
My terminal keep disconnect at a certain time. I had already search on google but most of it is about   "Write failed: Broken pipe."

Which I already solved that for years. I just found this new annoyed problems today

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su].

Comment: Are you behind a network firewall or proxy ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ? If so, can you post the solution as an answer so that other user's with the same issue can benefit from it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the following:
- The command that you were running
- You network Config
- Any logs from the instance
- Some information about your setup

Comment: @Faizan & George and every one  Thanks for the suggestion. The problems solved by switch to other wifi. It only happen when use wifi from my room. It quite no brainer but it just work and now that problem gone after change internet provider. 

That all what I can remember since there no response to the question back then I thought that no one found this is a problem so I didn't post how the problem gone. Just login to day and found someone have same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this problem as well and spent a few days trying to bisect it.

Like specified, playing with SSH KeepAlive parameters (`ClientAliveInterval`, `ClientAliveCountMax`, `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax`) or kernel TCP parameters (TCPKeepAlive on/off) does not solve the problem.

After playing with USB to Ethernet drivers and tcpdump, I realized the issue was due to the kernel 4.8 I was using. I switched the source (sending side) to 4.4 LTS and the problem disappeared (rsync via ssh and scp were working nicely again). The destination side can remain on 4.8 if you want, in my use case this was working (tested).

On the technical side, we can narrow a little bit the issue thanks to the wireshark dump below I made. We can see the TCP channel of the SSHv2 protocol is being reset (RST flag of TCP set to 1) causing the connection to abort. I don't know the cause of that RST yet. I need to make some bisection from 4.8.1 to 4.8.11 for that. [image]

I'm not saying your problem is specifically due to the kernel 4.8, but wrt. the date you posted your question/message, there are high chances you are currently using a kernel more recent than 4.4.

Comment: I'm having this problem. Running 4.9.8-1-ARCH as kernel.

Comment: @Bart Yep I'm still having the issue with 4.9.8 as well, this is why I recommend to switch back to the LTS branch of the kernel (I'm an Arch Linux user as well). With latest versions, the kernel has a bunch of stability issues for daily use.

Comment: I downgraded my kernel, the problem presisted, but it turned out to be a configuration issue.

Comment: @Bart could you specify the configuration issue it was?

Comment: Tried to configure an sftp-only account. Try the default sshd.config.

Comment: I'm getting back on this. The problem was not due to a buggy kernel, but to a buggy driver, especially the part dedicated to the hardware checksum offload. See [this thread for more info](https://linux-tips.com/t/how-to-solve-ssh-disconnect-packet-corrupt-problems/258).

Answer (score 2):

If that is an ssh connection, then you might want to make sure you send a keepalive message to the server.

Comment: Tried to put keepalive messages (Interval or enabling/disabling TCp keepalive) either on client or on server in config file or on the CLI line, but was not working on my side.
`rsync -av -e 'ssh -Y -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=10' --info=progress2 ~/dest/. root@IP:/mnt/share/dest`
Using 7.3p1 on both sides.

Comment: For me, setting ServerAliveInterval=300 worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

`ServerAliveInterval` seems to be the most common strategy to keep a connection alive. To prevent the broken pipe problem, here is the ssh config I useed in my `.ssh/ssh_config` file (may be named as `/etc/ssh/config` or `sshd_config`):

```
Host myhostshortcut
     HostName myhost.com
     User barthelemy
     ServerAliveInterval 60
     ServerAliveCountMax 10
```

Answer (score -3):

Connect through another wifi.

I don't know why or how it works, but it does.

The original poster sthapaun already mentioned this solution in a comment, but I want to add that the solution works for me, too.

Comment: Sorry. I retracted my flag. But in general, it is nice to make the answer a "community wiki" if it's an idea, someone else mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Can you link to me to a guide that explains that concept? I don't understand what you mean and would like to learn the better way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki
There is no rule, that you have to do it, but it's fair to do so.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the answer and converted to a wiki.

Comment: "I don't know why or how it works, but it does": it would be useful, here, if somebody could explain why it works